# Multiple exe writing to same log

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a Python (3.8) script compiled to *.exe which when a single instance of the program is run will write to its log (see code below) without any problems. However, when several instances of the executable are invoked by a 3rd party software nothing is written to the log file. I've tried having each instance of the *.exe write to it's own log file where the log filename had the PID of *.exe as a suffix, and here several log files were created, all with different filenames, but with no contents. Any idea what might be causing this behaviour? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

José Carlos

```
# LOG INITIALIZATION

fileNameNoExtension=os.path.splitext(sys.argv[0])[0]
log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(message)s')
logFile = fileNameNoExtension+'.log'   
my_handler = RotatingFileHandler(logFile, mode='a', maxBytes=10*1024*1024, backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=0)
my_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
my_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app_log = logging.getLogger('1')
app_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app_log.addHandler(my_handler)
```

Comment: Your code sets a logger called "1" to INFO, but that's not the root logger. Did you want `app_log = logginer.getLogger()` to get the root and apply the handler to all log messages?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. I've changed to 
`"app_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)"` 
and recompiled. All instances of the executable are now writing to the same log file. I do have some concurrency issues as I suspect I would but can live with that. As I'm logging the PID of every instance of the *.exe when debugging I can filter by the value of the PID.